# VM stuck in boot loop: Boot critical file C:\EFI\Microsoft\boot\resources\custom\bootres.dll is corrupt

Tags: windows-10, boot, uefi

A VM I built for a coworker has crashed and will not boot. It boots to a blue-screen. When I tried to run startup repair I found this in the error log:

```
Root cause found: 
Boot critical file C:\EFI\Microsoft\boot\resources\custom\bootres.dll is corrupt 
Repair action: File repair
Result: Failed. Error code = 0x57
Repair action: System files integrity check and repair
Result: Failed. Error code = 0x57
```

Looking online for this error, I cannot seem to find any conclusive way to fix this. Worth mentioning: I cloned this VM, so **I do have a copy of the original bootres.dll file**. Should I just try and replace the corrupted BootRes.DLL file? The VM is running on a VMware ESXi 6.0 hypervisor. The VM uses UEFI.

Comment: I was unable to fix this. I ended up just cloning a new VM and starting over. :(